# Real non-trivial zeros of Riemann zeta function inside critical strip

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Could someone please tell me what is known about the real non-trivial zeros of Riemann zeta function inside critical strip? Do we know there is none?

I want to know what is known about the above questions without the assumption of Riemann hypothesis.

Any hint or help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, we do know that there are no nontrivial zeros on the real line. You might want to see https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.09765 which shows that there is no nontrivial zeros $s=\sigma+it$ off of the critical line for $\vert t\vert\leq 3\times 10^{12}$

Comment: Perhaps, there should also be a more general comment here that for a general Dirichlet $L$ series $L(s,\chi)$ where $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character, the question of a real zero (known as a Siegel zero) is a difficult unresolved problem.

Comment: So, we know that $L(s,\chi)$ has no Siegel/exceptional zero, when $\chi=\chi_{0}$, right?But we don't know answer to this question for a character $\chi\neq \chi_{0}$.

Comment: Assuming that by $\chi_0$ you mean the trivial Dirichlet character then you are correct; however, for other characters we do know some things. For example for $\chi$ is a complex character (that is it takes values outside of $\mathbb{R}$, then there will not be any Siegel zeros. But if $\chi$ is real (say a quadratic character), then the existence of Siegel zeros is still open. But one could then talk about general $L$-series attached to other objects such as autommorphic forms

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are no real nontrivial zeroes of $\zeta(s)$ in $(0,1)$.

This can be easily shown as follows. Let $\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n/n^s$, which converges in $\mathop{\rm Re}s>0$. When $\mathop{\rm Re}s>1$, we have that
$$\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^s}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n)^s}=\left(1-\frac1{2^{1-s}}\right)\zeta(s).$$
Since $\eta(s)$ is holomorphic on $\mathop{\rm Re}s>0$, by analytic continuation this equality holds on $\mathop{\rm Re}s>0$ as well. Now, when $s$ is real and $0<s<1$, $\eta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty1/(2n+1)^s-1/(2n+2)^s$ and each term is positive, so $\eta(s)>0$, in particular $\eta(s)\ne0$, thus $\zeta(s)$ cannot vanish.